# Writing syntax for bivariate survival censored data to fit copula models in R

Tags: r, statistics

```html
library(Sunclarco)
library(MASS)
library(survival)
library(SPREDA)
library(SurvCorr)
library(doBy)

#Dataset
diabetes=data("diabetes")

data1=subset(diabetes,select=c("LASER","TRT_EYE","AGE_DX","ADULT","TIME1","STATUS1"))
data2=subset(diabetes,select=c("LASER","TRT_EYE","AGE_DX","ADULT","TIME2","STATUS2"))


#Adding variable which identify cluster
data1$CLUSTER<- rep(1,197)
data2$CLUSTER<- rep(2,197)

#Renaming the variable so that that we hve uniformity in the common items in the data
names(data1)[5] <- "TIME" 
names(data1)[6] <- "STATUS"
names(data2)[5] <- "TIME"
names(data2)[6] <- "STATUS"

#merge the files
Total_data=rbind(data1,data2)

# Re arranging the database 
diabete_full=orderBy(~LASER+TRT_EYE+AGE_DX,data=Total_data)
diabete_full

#using Sunclarco package for Clayton a nd Gumbel

Clayton_1step <- SunclarcoModel(data=diabete_full,time="TIME",status="STATUS",
                          clusters="CLUSTER",covariates=c("LASER","TRT_EYE","ADULT"),
                          stage=1,copula="Clayton",marginal="Weibull")
summary(Clayton_1step)

#              Estimates    StandardErrors

#lambda       0.01072631    0.005818201
#rho          0.79887565    0.058942208
#theta        0.10224445    0.090585891
#beta_LASER   0.16780224    0.157652947
#beta_TRT_EYE 0.24580489    0.162333369
#beta_ADULT   0.09324001    0.158931463

#              Estimate      StandardError
#Kendall's Tau 0.04863585    0.04099436



Clayton_2step <- SunclarcoModel(data=diabete_full,time="TIME",status="STATUS",
                                clusters="CLUSTER",covariates=c("LASER","TRT_EYE","ADULT"),
                                stage=2,copula="Clayton",marginal="Weibull")
summary(Clayton_1step)

#             Estimates    StandardErrors
#lambda       0.01131751    0.003140733
#rho          0.79947406    0.012428824
#beta_LASER   0.14244235    0.041845100
#beta_TRT_EYE 0.27246433    0.298184235
#beta_ADULT   0.06151645    0.253617142
#theta        0.18393973    0.151048024

#                Estimate     StandardError
#Kendall's Tau   0.08422381   0.06333791



Gumbel_1step <- SunclarcoModel(data=diabete_full,time="TIME",status="STATUS",
                                clusters="CLUSTER",covariates=c("LASER","TRT_EYE","ADULT"),
                                stage=1,copula="GH",marginal="Weibull")

#             Estimates     StandardErrors
#lambda       0.01794495     0.01594843
#rho          0.70636113     0.10313853
#theta        0.87030690     0.11085344
#beta_LASER   0.15191936     0.14187943
#beta_TRT_EYE 0.21469814     0.14736381
#beta_ADULT   0.08284557     0.14214373

#                Estimate      StandardError
#Kendall's Tau   0.1296931     0.1108534



Gumbel_2step <- SunclarcoModel(data=diabete_full,time="TIME",status="STATUS",
                               clusters="CLUSTER",covariates=c("LASER","TRT_EYE","ADULT"),
                               stage=2,copula="GH",marginal="Weibull")
```

Am required to fit copula models in R for different copula classes particularly the Gaussian, FGM,Pluckett and possibly Frank (if i still have time). The data am using is Diabetes data available in R through the package Survival and Survcorr.

Its my thesis am working on and its a study for the exploratory purposes to see how does copula class serves different purposes as in results they lead to having different results on the same. I found a package Sunclarco in Rstudio which i was able to fit Clayton and Gumbel copula class but its not available yet for the other classes.

The challenge am facing is that since i have censored data which has to be incorporated in likelihood estimation then it becomes harder fro me to write a syntax since as I don't have a strong programming background. In addition, i have to incorporate the covariates present in programming and see their impact on the association if it present or not. However, taking to my promoter he gave me insights on how to approach the syntax writing for this puzzle which goes as follows

•   ******First of all, forget about the likelihood function. We only work with the log-likelihood function. In this way, you do not need to take the product of the contributions over each of the observations, but can take the sum of the log-contributions over the different observations.

•   Next, since we have a balanced design, we can use the regular data frame structure in which we have for each cluster only one row in the data frame. The different variables such as the lifetimes, the indicators and all the covariates are the columns in this data frame.

•   Due to the bivariate setting, there are only 4 possible ways to give a contribution to the log-likelihood function: both uncensored, both censored, first uncensored and second censored, or first censored and second uncensored. Well, to create the loglikelihood function, you create a new variable in your data frame in which you put the correct contribution of the log-likelihood based on which individual in the couple is censored. When you take the sum of this variable, you have the value of the log-likelihood function.

•   Since this function depends on parameters, you can use any optimizer, like optim or nlm to get your optimal values. By careful here, optim and nlm look for the minimum of a function, not a maximum. This is easy solved since the minimum of a function -f is the same as the maximum of a function f.

•   Since you have for each copula function, the different expressions for the derivatives, it should be possible to get the likelihood functions now.******

Am still struggling to find a way as for each copula class each of the likelihood changes as the generator function is also unique for the respective copula since it needs to be adapted during estimation. Lastly, I should run analysis for both one and two steps of copula estimations as i will use to compare results.

if someone could help me to figure it out then I will be eternally grateful. Even if for just one copula class e.g. Gaussian then I will figure it the rest based on the one that am requesting to be assisted since I tried everything and still i have nothing to show up for and now i feel time is running out to get answers by myself.

Comment: I don't see any code or data here. Statistical methods questions belong on CrossValidated.com. You should also use [edit] facilites to fix your current failure to capitalize properly. SO is not a chat room. You are expected to use your shift-key.

Comment: i just reply your comments, thanks

Comment: I get an error from the `subset` calls complaining about no "subset" argument. Why not use "[" instead if all you want to do is select columns? After correcting that error and using my GUI's Data Manager instead of your call to `data`, I now getting a "system is exactly singular" error with the second SunclarcoModel-call. This still appears to be a request for statistical consultation and does seem to be a coding question yet. For coding questions, you should know "how" (at least abstractly) to solve your problem and what the right answer should be. I do admit to not knowing the Sunclarco pkg.